# Размещение кнопок в активити

Tags: java, android, button, layout

Можно ли как-то быстро выстроить кнопки как показано на картинке? Через RelativeLayout - долго, пробовал через LinearLayout, но там ориентация только horizontal или vertical, есть ли еще способы?

[image: buttons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте GridLayout для версий API 21+ (или support.v7.widget.GridLayout для более ранних версий) и задайте для кнопок вес:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:rowCount="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    ...
```

Для использования support `GridLayout`, добавьте в `Gradle` `implementation com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1` (последняя версия).