# Android создание таблицы

Tags: java, android

Необходимо расположить элементы в виде таблицы.
Посмотрев примере, понял что есть несколько способов

1. TableLayout, TableRow (как понял устарел)
2. GridView
3. GridLayout.

Какой из них лучше использовать?

Comment: смотря, что вы хотите получить. Из приведенного всегда предпочитал GridLayout :)

Comment: Просто я между ними отличий не вижу. Необходимо для динамического создания (заполнения) данными, либо TextView с текстом

Comment: как насчет `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`? Grid и Tab Layout обычно не скролляться, `GridView` устарел и проигрывает `RecyclerView`

Comment: Ок, тогда GridLayout. Не приведете литературу, статьи по динамическому созданию, добавлению элементов в него

Comment: Там все просто. Как `Linear` в `Linear` с возможностью устанавливать вес. Единственный нюанс - для работы на апи < 21 нужно использовать `support GridLayout`. Здесь недавно отвечал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843605/Размещение-кнопок-в-активити/843612#843612

Comment: как можно сделать как бы padding внутри каждой ячейки в GridLayout? Чтобы текст не наежал

Comment: просто не охота для каждого элемента margin прописывать

Comment: По-моему нет. Чтобы для каждого элемента не прописывать `padding` - используйте стили (заодно запишите туда ширину и высоту 0). Если добавляете динамически, добавьте пару строчек/функцию в код перед добавлением. Как вариант: после создания (если нединамически) пробегайтесь по всем чайлдам и выставляйте паддинги программно

Comment: динамически добавляется

Comment: Не поможете с этим? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845097/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82-fragment-%D0%BA-fragmenttab

Comment: видел этот вопрос, но с табами давно не работал, уже не помню. Придет мысль - оформлю